# My kivy app closes after a button press if the button callback has a function from another file in it

Tags: python, kivy

The function which is called when the button is pressed

```py
def Button1_Callback(instance):
    show_popup()
    Greet.timex()
    print(f"Button {instance.text} was pressed.")
```

The popup funtion :

```py
def show_popup():
    layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 5)
    label = Label(text="executing request")
    layout.add_widget(label)
    pop = Popup(title="Status", content = layout, size_hint = (None, None),  size=(200, 200), auto_dismiss=True)
    pop.open()
```

and the function which is inside `Button1_Callback`

```py
def timex():                                                                    # replies with current time
    y = time.strftime("%I %M %P")
    engine.say("The time is " + y + "M")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

this function is in another file which is name `Greet.py`

When I run this app, the code works fine
but when i click on the button the `timex` function will execute and the app will stop automatically

also if i comment the line `Greet.timex()` and run the code then the problem doest occur
it only occurs if there is a function inside `Button1_Callback`

Comment: No error message?

Comment: @JohnAnderson nope no error messages

`[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...` This line gets printed after the button press

Answer (score 0):

you must run the function in the ui thread (when you press button the function sarted do not start from ui thread) otherwise your app will stop working
try that.

```
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
def Button1_Callback(instance):
    show_popup()
    run_on_ui_thread(Greet.timex)() #here we are making new function that will run on ui thread .
    print(f"Button {instance.text} was pressed.")
```

***Happy coding***

Comment: how do i install android package.
I tried to install [android for python](https://pypi.org/project/python-for-android/) but it gave me module not found error.

Comment: add android with requirement file in buildozer. like that // requirements=python3,kivy,android